# How to get Azure VM reboot and shutdown logs into Azure Log Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-alerts

Is there any way to get Azure VM **reboot** and **shutdown** logs into Azure Log Analytics Workspace?

I already mapped **syslog and daemon & Kern log** into Azure Log Analytics Workspace but I couldn't get any log message related to VM Reboot and shutdown even though I rebooted the VM.

Anyone have an idea to accomplish this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you perform a reboot from the Azure portal, Azure PowerShell AZ CLI, or the API, then an event will be generated in the Azure Activity Log. You can send activity logs to a Log Analytics workspace. Instructions for configuring the integration between activity logs and log analytics can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log-collect)

Comment: Actually I need to capture from VM's command line reboot and auto-reboot events due to updates. Is there any way to get those logs?

Comment: They should appear on the System logs of the VM/OS itself. Assuming you're running a Linux VM the specific log file could vary depending on distribution